# Proof of double counting formula

Tags: solution-verification, discrete-geometry

Let $v_k$ be the number of vertices of degree $k$, V and E the set of vertices and edges respectively. Then $|V| = \sum_k v_k$.

I have to show the **double counting formula** for a closed surface:
$$ \sum_k kv_k = 2|E| $$

I would like to give a rigorous proof. I was searching on the internet and I found proofs that explain the intuition.

I was thinking about and I got something like this:

$$ \sum_{k} k v_k =\sum_{v_i \in V} d_i = \sum_{v_i \in V} \sum_{(v_i v_k) \in E} 1 \stackrel{(1)}{=} \sum_{(v_i v_k) \in E} \sum_{ v \in \{v_i, v_k \}} 1 = \sum_{(v_i v_k) \in E} 2 = 2|E| $$

but I am not sure if this is correct, especially in the step (1). Note that $d_i$ is the degree of $v_i$.

- How could I improve/correct this proof?
- What would be the correct proof? Or where could I find the correct one?

Comment: You can add all the entries in the incidence matrix in two ways: add all the row sums for the LHS, and all the column sums for the RHS. This is essentially what you are doing above too (which is fine btw).